# Python 2.7 fabric/paramiko EOF when trying to untar a remote file

Tags: python, python-2.7, eof, fabric

I am trying to remotely untar a file using fabric 0.92, but am receiving an EOF from paramiko.

```py
def deployFile(self, localdir, remoteroot, filename):
    log.info('Deploying file {0} to host {1}...'.format(filename, self.host))
    env.password = self.password
    env.disable_known_hosts = True
    localFile=localdir+"/"+filename
    remoteFile='/tmp/{0}'.format(filename)

    with settings(host_string = self.connectstring):
        log.info('...putting {0}'.format(filename))
        put(localFile, "/tmp/", mode=0755)
        with cd(remoteroot):
            untar='tar zxvf {0}'.format(remoteFile)
            log.info('...untarring {0}'.format(filename))
            #paramiko.util.log_to_file('paramiko.out')
            sudo(untar, pty=True)
```

My output from paramiko.out:

```
DEB [20110205-20:49:36.782] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 8] Max packet in: 34816 bytes
DEB [20110205-20:49:36.784] thr=2   paramiko.transport: [chan 7] EOF received (7)
DEB [20110205-20:49:36.785] thr=2   paramiko.transport: [chan 8] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
INF [20110205-20:49:36.785] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Secsh channel 8 opened.
DEB [20110205-20:49:36.788] thr=2   paramiko.transport: EOF in transport thread
```

I am able to perform other sudo commands using fabric, but untarring a file seems to break.  I have compared the md5sum of the local file and of the remote file, and they are equal.  I am able to untar the file without errors when I log into the remote machine.

Comment: I got the same error today using fabric.contrib.project.upload_project, but maybe you want to use upload_project, it will save you some complexity. I used fabric.contrib.project.rsync_project instead because it worked. Maybe this is a bug.fab --version Fabric 1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Is this still an issue in the new Fabric release for you? Also you might try dropping the verbose flag on the tar. Could perhaps be flooding the stdout/stdin pipes.